# Как добавить список куки в CefSharp?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Есть `.txt` файл с 14 куками. 1 строка = 1 куки.

Как их всех добавить в запрос и авторизоваться на сайте при помощи куки?

[C#] [CefSharp]

```
string sitename = "vk.com";

private void Input(string sitename)
    {
        chromiumWebBrowser1.Load(sitename);
        string link = chromiumWebBrowser1.Address;
        var cookieManager = chromiumWebBrowser1.GetCookieManager(null);
        Cookie cookies = new Cookie();
        foreach(string str in cookie)
        {
            string[] c = str.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            cookies.Name = c[5];
            cookies.Value = c[6];
            cookies.Path = "/";
            cookies.Domain = c[0];
        }
        cookieManager.SetCookie(link, cookies);
    }
```

Comment: покажите ваш код, что у вас сейчас есть и расскажите что вы пытались сделать

Comment: @tym32167 дополнил. Работать работает но куки не отправляеются

Comment: судя по коду, вы мнеяете один и тот же экземпляр `cookies`

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я так и понял, но как тогда добавить список куков?